# Jenkins login page is not being displayed after deploying artifact to Tomcat with InteliJ IDEA

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, intellij-idea

I've set HTTP port for Tomcat to 8081, but after deploying artifact jenkins-war:war I see Tomcat's page under this port, not Jenkins's. What did I wrong?
My aim is to debug in Tomcat.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, did you use a  deployment context for the jenkins application? Did you use this context in your url?

Comment: You cant have two application running on the same port ...try changing the ports